# Dimension of a subset of $\ell_2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I am wondering whether the following space is a finite-dimensional subset of $\ell_2$ or an infinite-dimensional one?

$$S(\ell_2)= \{ (x_1,x_2,\ldots) \in \ell_2 \mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty (nx_n)^2 <\infty \}$$

Notice that operator $L(x_1,x_2,...)=(x_1/1,x_2/2,...)$ is a compact one to one operator and thus it can not have an infinite dimensional range. Hence, the dimension of $S(\ell_2)$ comes into question.

Answer (score 4):

Let $e_k = (0,0,0,\ldots,0,0,1,0,0,\ldots)$ where the $1$ is in the $k$th place and all other entries are $0$.  This belongs to your proposed space.

The set $\{e_k : k=1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: OK, is there any tool to assess how big an infinite dimensional subspace of an infinite dimensional space is? One will be this: Is this subspace dense in $l_2$ or not? what do you propose for another test/tool?

Comment: @SaraWinslet, certainly as the linear span of $e_k$'s is dense, so is $S(\ell_2)$.

Comment: @TomekKania notice the linear span of $e_k$'s may not lay in $S(l_2)$

Comment: @SaraWinslet : The linear span of the $e_k$s is the set of all FINITE linear combinations of them.  All of those do lie $S(\ell_2)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy This does not give any idea about the dimension of subspace. Notice when we are talking about subspace, we implicitly mean "closed linear subspace".

Comment: @SaraWinslet : My example shows that the space $S(\ell_2)$ is not finite-dimensional because for every finite cardindal number it shows there is a linearly independent set in that space with more than that many members.  Closures of infinite-dimensional subspaces don't matter to this.  However, the closure within $S(\ell_2)$ of the linear span set I've described is the set of all points in $S(\ell_2)$ that are limit points of the linear span of the set I described.  As such, it is a subset of $S(\ell_2)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @SaraWinslet : $\ldots\,{}$and if you write "linear span", I construe that to mean the set of all finite linear combinations.  If you say "subspace", even if I construed that to mean "closed linear subspace", that's no reason why "linear span" should be construed differently from the way I construed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: No, in no way does "subspace" implicitly mean "closed linear subspace".